# change href link in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm creating a new DOM element so I can later populate it with data:

```
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);
```

I want to iterate over links in this newly created element to turn
addresses like "something.something" into "http://www.something.something".
I don't want jQuery, so I tried this without success:

```
var links = bubbleDOM.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].href = "http://www." + links[i].href.value;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say `links` is? Is it finding anything?

Comment: i'm not using any debugger mate

Comment: When/how are the link tags added to bubbleDom?

Comment: You should always try debugging JS before asking the community.

Comment: @Tom: How on earth do you write reliable code without a debugger?

Comment: @josh.trow, well apparently he doesn't... =/

Comment: @josh.trow i ried putting an aert inside the loop..but nothing happens so there isn't anything there

Comment: @Tom: You need to give us a fully failing page to test on - those code snippets you provided will do something (though as Mike Samuel pointed out, not exactly what you want).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things stand out.

1. `links[i].href.value` isn't valid. Just use `links[i].href`.
2. You should check to make sure the href actually has something in it.

Here is an example that works for me:

```
var links = bubbleDOM.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    if (!!links[i].href && links[i].href.length > 0) { // Check that there is an href
        links[i].href = "http://www." + links[i].href;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`links[i].href.value` will always be an absolute URL, so if the attribute in HTML looks like

```
<a href="something.something">
```

then the value of `links[i].href.value` will be something like

```
"http://current.domain/something.something"
```

Try using `getAttribute('href')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

use getters and setter to access/modify the attributes : `getAttribute` and `setAttribue`.

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rF9qk/

Comment: hey thanks. it's not even getting inside the loop.. tried to put an alert inside it.. i know there are 15 links so would could be the problem?

Comment: could you post a fiddle with your code, or link us to your page?